# How to link input text file to C++ program

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, io, clion

I'm trying to write a C++ program in CLion that opens, manipulates, and closes an input file and output file. The input file is a .txt file, but when I execute the program, it can't find the input file even though it's in the same directory as the .cpp program it's executing from. I was wondering if it was because I had to link the input file with CMake, but I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with configuring CMake. How can I link a .txt file to a C++ project?

Comment: Your executable is probably not linked with the text file you are trying to read. Please show the code.

Comment: What happens at runtime is not related to how you compile or link a program. How do you open the file you want to read?

Comment: There's resource file "linkage" in some exotic environments. I said "probably not".

Comment: @TedLyngmo The "exotic environment" in question is Windows. So we'd be talking about a resource compiler. But i doubt that.

Comment: @Swordfish Me too, but I only put "probably" in there because I'm not 100% sure. There are many environments targeting Windows and I don't know them well enough.

Comment: I **guess** that your program opens a file using its name, without a directory. This will work if you **run** the program from the directory where the file is located. Please, clarify your question post. Currently it is **unclear** what your have and what do your want to achieve. The phrase "link the input file" is unclear by itself and doesn't help in understanding the question. If you don't know the rigth wording, then show some parts of your code which shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "link" a text file to an executable file. In CLion, the default behavior is to build the project binary into a folder called `cmake-build-debug`. The text file you want to use as your input has to be in the same directory as the `.exe` file, not the `.cpp`, so what you would have to do in this case is prepend a `../` to the name of the text file (i.e... if your file is called `input.txt`, the C code would say something like

```
FILE* input_file = fopen("../input.txt", "r");
```

Remember to check for return codes, errors, etc.

---

The above solution is not good for a variety of reasons; first of all, you're hard coding a filename, which is at best a huge limitation and at worst pointless. A better solution would be to pass in the name of the file via the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    FILE* inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    ...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This solution is still not great, however, primarily because you should always sanitize your inputs, never just accepting string input from the user and simply using it right away. This is a huge security liability. I also didn't check return codes or anything; I simply verified `argc` was two. (Remember that a program will always have `argc` at least equal to `1`, since the first argument is the program's name.)

---

To answer your actual question (the one you asked, though not necessarily the one you needed an answer to), you can use CMake's `find_file` [function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_file.html) to "link" to a file. You're not actually linking anything, really, the `find_file` function simply returns the full path to a named file, but you can then pass this information as a parameter to your program as discussed previously.

You can do more than might be immediately obvious with CMake, actually; [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) is the documentation for their file-related functions.

You can also execute your newly-built program from CMake directly, using the `execute_process` function. The function actually takes an `INPUT_FILE` parameter directly, so you can set a variable for the path of your input file, set it using the result of `find_file`, then directly execute the program with your input file using `execute_process`.

Comment: Thank you! I also contacted JetBrains on this problem, and they said the same thing. I just placed the input file in the `cmake-build-debug` directory, ran the program, and the output file was created there. This helps a lot, and your response is very detailed. Also, the reason my program is taking strings from a specific file is because it's what's required for my college C++ class. Hopefully, we'll learn more advanced ways to use input files. Thanks again for your answer!